# Grabbing individual numbers from a user entered number and checking is it is either odd or even index

Tags: java

Trying to write a program that takes all digits at odd index and should be added to form the sum.
**Example:** if the credit card number is 43589795, then you form the sum 3 + 8 + 7 + 5 is 23.

Then double each of the digits that are at even index and add all digits of the resulting numbers to the sum.
**Example:** The numbers above, doubling the digits yields 8 10 18 18. Adding all digits in these values yields 8 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 8 + 1 + 8 is 27, so the final sum total is 23 + 27 which is 50. If the last digit of the final sum is 0, the credit card number is valid. In our case the last digit of 50 is 0, so the number is valid.

I would greatly appreciate some help I'm trying to understand for loops better and using Character.isDigit. Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CreditCard {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        final String CREDIT_CARD = "[0-9]{8}";
        int length = 8;
        String num, response;
        char ch1, ch2;

       do {
           do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a 8 digit credit cardnumber");//validating that the user entered 8 digits.
            num = scan.next();
               ch1 = num.charAt(0);
           } while (!num.matches(CREDIT_CARD));

        for (int i = 0; i < CREDIT_CARD.length(); i++){ //for loop for checking if number is at odd or even index?
            Character.isDigit(ch1); //Trying to use Character.isDigit to validate whether it is at odd or even index?
            if (ch1 % 2== 1 ){

            }
        }





           System.out.println("Would you like to enter a different card?");
           response = scan.next();
    }while (response.equals("yes")); //Do while loop asking if user wants to enter another card.

        System.out.println("Goodbye!");


    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please find solution. Here we are first checking if character present in card number is digit or not. If not we are breaking loop and printing invalid. If digit is valid than we are performing operations on the basis of index. When location is odd we are again counting total digit value of number.

```
            int sum = 0;
            Boolean isValidCard = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
                ch1 = num.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isDigit(ch1)) {
                    if (i % 2 == 1) {
                        sum += ((int) ch1 - 48);
                    } else {
                        int temp = (2 * ((int) ch1 - 48));
                        while (temp > 0) {
                            sum += temp % 10;
                            temp = temp / 10;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    isValidCard = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isValidCard) {
                System.out.println("CC Invalid");
            } else if (sum % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.println("CC is valid");
            }
```

Comment: Dudes are you really immatures?? Down-voting without providing reasons??